# GraphLab and SFrames

Tags: python, graphlab, sframe

I am new to python and I'm taking a machine learning course. I have few experience of GraphLab and SFrames.  I'd like to know how to apply a conditional and logical operation in case of data stored as SFrames. The following code and output might help to understand the problem:

```
import graphlab as gl
data_1 = gl.Sframe("home_data.gl/')
```

It has a integer column named 'sqft_living'. I want to find all the values that lie between 2000 to 4000 sqft in this specific column.

Can anyone please suggest how to implement it?

Comment: You didn't provide any output. (Or input.)

Answer (score 0):

The code below will work fine for filtering:

```
x = data_1[(data_1['sqft_living']>=2000) & (data_1['sqft_living'] <=4000)]
```

The filtered data will be stored in x.